# Debugging SSIS Script Task

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am busy developing a SSIS solution targeting SQL Server 2012, but I have a problem trying to debug a SSIS Script Task in Visual Studio 2015. Once I have set the breakpoint in the script project and try and execute the package, an exception is being thrown as per screenshot below:

Package execution exception

[image]

I have tried setting the Run64BitRuntime to false, but it has made no difference whatsoever.

I have noticed that the ScriptLanguage is set to Microsoft Visual C# 2010, even though I am using Visual Studio 2015. When I edit the script it opens up the project using Visual Studio 2015. Not sure if this has anything to do with it...

I have also uninstalled all previous versions of Visual Studio including 2010 and 2012. Uninstalled SSDT for Visual Studio 2010 and 2012. Repaired my SQL Server 2012 installation and also repaired my Visual Studio 2015 installation. Reinstalled SSDT for Visual Studio 2015, but it still hasn't made any difference.

Out of desperation, I then changed the TargetServerVersion to SQL Server 2014 on the solution and voila! I can debug the script project.

This poses a problem because deploying the solution to SQL Server 2012 and executing the package via SQL Server Agent, the jobs fails with the message

> Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.5058.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    An invalid reporting option was specified.  Only E, W, I, C, D, P, V, and N are allowed.  The command line parameters are invalid.  The step failed.

Setting the TargetServerVersion back to SQL Server 2012 and redeploying the solution, it then executes the job successfully. So my guess is that the backwards compatibility issue with SSIS that was supposedly fixed in the new SSDT version, is not really fixed.

I would hate to flip flop between SQL Server 2014 and 2012 as the TargetServerVersion during development to debug and then to deploy.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Please add the code for your script task to the question.

Comment: @NickHeidke The code for the script task is irrelevant, as I experience the same behavior with a script task created in it's default template state with a breakpoint set on the line `Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;`

Comment: I see that now, sorry I can't help on this one. Your best bet may be to engage Microsoft, I think you've found a bug.

Comment: @NickHeidke Thank you for the input. I suspect it might be a bug. Only way I would know, is to do a clean installation of Windows and Visual Studio 2015 along with SSDT for Visual Studio 2015 and see if it still behaves in the same manner. That way I can eliminate that it's due to a registry entry conflict / registered DLL conflict. Unfortunately I don't have that luxury at this point in time.